# escondendo componente input ao selecionar um valor no campo select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html-select

Tenho um componente `select` que traz os países do banco de dados

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">  
  <label>País *:</label> 
  <select required="required" id="selecionaPais" ng-model="pessoasEnderecos.pais.idPais" 
          class="form-control">
    <option value="" ></option>
    <option value="{{paises.idPais}}" ng-repeat="pais in paises">{{pais.nome}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Quero fazer com que, ao ser selecionado o país Brasil, o `input` cidade fique escondido

```
<div id="idCidade">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Cidade:</label> 
    <input maxlength="20" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="estrangeiro.nome" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por qual propriedade você identificar que o país é Brasil?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema, jovem? Precisa que alguma coisa seja melhorada em uma das respostas?

Comment: @LINQ eu só não consegui implementar por os exemplos das respostas foram com dados fixos..

Comment: Mas qual a diferença? O exemplo da minha resposta usa um _array_, com a mesma base estrutural do que o array que você usa na sua aplicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está usando AngularJS, é só criar uma regrinha usando uma diretiva **`ng-show`**.

Você sabe que o ID do pais selecionado será salvo em **`pessoasEnderecos.pais.idPais`**, a partir daí é só fazer

```
ng-show="pessoasEnderecos.pais.idPais != ID_DO_BRASIL"
```

no input (ou div, ou qualquer elemento) que pretendes esconder quando o pais selecionado for o Brasil.

Veja um exemplo rodando:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainController', function() {  
  let ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.idBrasil = 1;
  ctrl.pessoasEnderecos = { pais : { } };
  
  ctrl.paises = [
    { idPais: 1, nome: 'Brasil', },
    { idPais: 2, nome: 'Portugal' },
    { idPais: 3, nome: 'Noruega' },
    { idPais: 4, nome: 'Japão' }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">  
  <label>País *:</label> 
   <select required="required" id="selecionaPais" 
           ng-model="ctrl.pessoasEnderecos.pais.idPais" 
           class="form-control" 
           ng-options="pais.idPais as pais.nome for pais in ctrl.paises">      
    </select>
  </div>
    
  <div id="idCidade" ng-show="ctrl.pessoasEnderecos.pais.idPais != ctrl.idBrasil">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Cidade:</label> 
      <input maxlength="20" type="text" class="form-control" 
       ng-model="estrangeiro.nome"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo de como você poderia fazer isso com `jQuery`, a diferença básica mesmo será que, ao invés de colocar os valores já predefinidos nos `options` como coloquei no exemplo abaixo, você trará esses esses valores do banco de dados colocando-os nos `values` dos `options` do `select`:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#selecionaPais').change(function() {
    var pais = $('#selecionaPais').val();
    switch (pais) {
      case '':
        $('#idCidade').show();
        break;
      case 'Brasil':
        //Oculta a div do campo cidade
        $('#idCidade').hide();
        break;
      case 'EUA':
        $('#idCidade').show();
        break;
      default:
        $('#idCidade').show();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">  
        <label>País *:</label> 
       <select required="required" id="selecionaPais" ng-model="pessoasEnderecos.pais.idPais" class="form-control">
        <option value=''>Selecione o país</option>
        <option value='Brasil'>Brasil</option>
        <option value='Argentina'>Argentina</option>
        <option value='EUA'>Estados Unidos</option>
      </select>
</div>
<br>
<div id="idCidade">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Cidade:</label> <input maxlength="20"  type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="estrangeiro.nome" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você precisará observar toda vez que o valor do seu `select` for alterado e quando o valor alterado for igual ao valor da opção "Brasil" então você deverá ocultar o `input`.

Você pode fazer isso de diversas formas, segue explicação de como fiz no exemplo abaixo:

1. Coloquei uma chamada de função no [onChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange) do `<select>` que passará o valor da `<option>` selecionada como parâmetro.
2. Coloquei um `id` no seu `<input />` de país para identificá-lo na função.
3. A função receberá o valor da `<option>` selecionada se a mesma for Brasil ocultará o `<input />`.

```js
function OcultaCidade(opcaoSelecionada){
  var inputCidade = document.getElementById("inputCidade");

  if(opcaoSelecionada == "BR"){
    inputCidade.style.display = "none";
  }else{
    inputCidade.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">  
  <label>País *:</label> 
  <select required id="selecionaPais" class="form-control" onchange="OcultaCidade(this.value)">
    <option value="EUA">Estados Unidos</option>
    <option value="BR">Brasil</option>    
    <option value="ES">Espanha</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="idCidade">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Cidade:</label>
    <input maxlength="20" id="inputCidade" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```